# React-Native : Is there any possibility to close all the opened Modals in single call?

Tags: react-native

It's a common thing to open `Modal` over `Modal` and so on. Let's say I have opened total four `Modals` one upon another one. Now I would like to close all four `Modals` in single call. I have opened Modals in following sequence,

> From 1'st Modal to 2'nd Modal => From 2'nd Modal to 3'd Modal => From
> 3'rd Modal to 4'th Modal

Is it possible to close all four modals from 4'th Modal, at once?

Comment: Is setting the `visible` props for each of them all at once an option?

Comment: I am setting `Visible` prop when ever I have to open the `Modal`. But not at once

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about 2 solutions:

1. Have different states for each modal and therefore once you want to close them all simultaneously you set each state to false.
2. Have a separate class component with that Modal, where you have a method called `setVisible(value)`. And where you have all 4 modals, you can set to each one a `ref`. Therefore when you want to close them all, you just call the `setVisible` method from each ref

Maybe you can share some code if what I've said seems unclear.